# Pandas: How can I add many new columns (one-hot encode table) based on one column (which contains list)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here's my problem. Given a sample pandas dataframe (lists in `colB` can contains only numbers from 0 to n (in this example 5)):

```
   colA       colB
0     0  [2, 4, 5]
1     1     [0, 1]
2     2        [0]
3     4        [5]
4     4     [2, 5]
```

I am trying to do something like this: (in my example, 5 new columns with 0 or 1 based on `colB`)

```
   colA       colB  colB0  colB1  colB2  colB4  colB5
0     0  [2, 4, 5]      0      0      1      1      1
1     1     [0, 1]      1      1      0      0      0
2     2        [0]      1      0      0      0      0
3     4        [5]      0      0      0      0      1
4     4     [2, 5]      0      0      1      0      1
```

I have done it with: `iterrows()`. However, it's really slow when I got 900k rows. Is there any efficient solution? Thanks for answers.

Comment: please explain how your columns look like? because this doesn't look like a dataframe to me

Comment: @ezzeddin to simplify, lets say there's only one column and every element in this column is a list, example: `pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,4,5],[0,1],[0],[5],[2,5]]), dtype=object) ` and I want add 6 columns in this example (because list can contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). If I got list [2, 4, 5] in first row I want to add 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 in this order to new columns. If I got [0, 1] i want 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0. If [0] than 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the list in `colB` into **one-hot encode** table by:

1. join the elements in list using [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and `join`
2. generate the **one-hot encode** table by [`.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)
3. add prefix to the generated column labels by [`.add_prefix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
df_exp = (df['colB'].map(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, x)))
                    .str.get_dummies()
                    .add_prefix('colB')
         )
```

**Alternatively**, you can also generate the **one-hot encode** table by:

```
df_exp = (pd.get_dummies(df['colB'].explode())
            .groupby(level=0).max()
            .add_prefix('colB')
         )
```

**Data Input:**

```
data = {'colA': [0, 1, 2, 4, 4], 'colB': [[2, 4, 5], [0, 1], [0], [5], [2, 5]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   colA       colB
0     0  [2, 4, 5]
1     1     [0, 1]
2     2        [0]
3     4        [5]
4     4     [2, 5]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_exp)

   colB0  colB1  colB2  colB4  colB5
0      0      0      1      1      1
1      1      1      0      0      0
2      1      0      0      0      0
3      0      0      0      0      1
4      0      0      1      0      1
```

4. attach the generated **one-hot encode** table to the original dataframe

```
df_out = df.join(df_exp)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   colA       colB  colB0  colB1  colB2  colB4  colB5
0     0  [2, 4, 5]      0      0      1      1      1
1     1     [0, 1]      1      1      0      0      0
2     2        [0]      1      0      0      0      0
3     4        [5]      0      0      0      0      1
4     4     [2, 5]      0      0      1      0      1
```

### To do it in one step:

Use either:

```
df_out = df.join(df['colB'].map(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, x)))
                           .str.get_dummies()
                           .add_prefix('colB')
                 )
```

Or, use:

```
df_out = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['colB'].explode())
                   .groupby(level=0).max()
                   .add_prefix('colB')
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative, based on `explode`+`unstack`:

```
df.join(df.explode('colB')
   .set_index('colB', append=True)
   .unstack()
   .notna()
   .astype(int)
   .droplevel(0,1)
   .reindex(range(5), axis=1)
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .add_prefix('colB')
 )
```

Output:

```
  colA       colB  colB0  colB1  colB2  colB3  colB4
0    0  [2, 4, 5]      0      0      1      0      1
1    1     [0, 1]      1      1      0      0      0
2    2        [0]      1      0      0      0      0
3    4        [5]      0      0      0      0      0
4    4     [2, 5]      0      0      1      0      0
```